# Define list of triggers to execute job

Tags: c#, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I would like to execute same job in different scheduled times.
Here is one sample which I wrote:

```
  ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    var setoftrigs = new HashSet<ITrigger>();
    for (int x=0; x<=2; x++)
    {
        setoftrigs.Add(TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("trigger" + x.ToString(), "group1").WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(21, 44+x)).Build());                
    }
    
    // get a scheduler
    IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    sched.Start();
    
    // create job
    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<RunJob>()
    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .Build();
   
     sched.ScheduleJob(job, setoftrigs, false);
```

The problem is that in certain time jobs is not executed.

But if I do on this way:

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
.WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
.WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(21, 49))
.Build();

sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

...it works fine.

What I want to achieve is to have a list of triggers when job should be executed.
How to do that?

Comment: How do you verify if the job is triggered or not? From the code it looks like the jobs are triggered for `21:44`, `21:45`, `21:46`. Are you checking for the same times?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I verify on way that one function is executed. In this example above the function is not executed.